# Replace column names, table names and other structures using a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to search the structure of my MySQL db and replace structures that contain or equal "xyz*"... column names and table names are the main thing, but I'd like to search all structures.

Then, I want to replace "xyz*" with "abcdefg".

Answer (score 0):

I doubt one can do this with one query. What you can do is create ALTER statements. I would write a small program (in the language of your choice) and
first I would get the table names like this:

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables;
```

The result set has to be checked in a loop, if there is a table named "xyz*" then create an ALTER statement:

```
RENAME TABLE tbl_name TO new_tbl_name
```

For the colums, you would have to get each Table again, then all colums for each table:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_name';
```

the again a loop to change the columns name, this time using `ALTER TABLE`.

see also:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html